# How to add a button to a chart by a user control in C#?

Tags: c#, charts, user-controls

I want to customise a chart in C# and add two buttons to it for zoom in and zoom out. I started adding 2 buttons in Visual Studio toolbox and encountered a problem that once I have added new controls to my project I lost the main feature of the chart in properties like ChartAreas, Legends, Series...

My code is below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting;

namespace DemoCustomGraph
{
    public partial class customGraph : UserControl
    {
        public customGraph()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        private void btnScrollOnOff_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].CursorX.AutoScroll == false)
            {
                chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].CursorX.AutoScroll = true;
                btnScrollOnOff.Text = "Scroll On";
            }
            else
            {
                chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].CursorX.AutoScroll = false;
                btnScrollOnOff.Text = "Scroll Off";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: MSChart has a nice zoom in/out function built-in. If you want to use it inside a UserControl make sure that the Chart control is public..!

Comment: Is `chart1` part of the UserControl `customGraph`?

Comment: _make sure that the Chart control is public_ To do so select the chart in your UC and go to the properties pane and change the __modifier__ from `private`  to `internal` or `public`. You still won't be able to change the uc's chart in the designer but you can now access it in code..